# Explicitly define stages in Gitlab CI for sequential job execution?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

According to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages)

> If stages is not defined in the .gitlab-ci.yml file, the default
> pipeline stages are:
>
> ```
> .pre
> build
> test
> deploy
> .post
> ```

Now I have this sample `.gitlab-ci.yml` file without defining stages:

```
job_build:
  stage: build
  
job_deploy:
  stage: deploy
```

Since default stages are defined, I assume these jobs will be executed sequentially, but, upon checking the pipelines UI, it appears the Gitlab runners executed the jobs in parallel.

Now I tried explicitly defining stages like so:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

job_build:
  stage: build
  
job_deploy:
  stage: deploy
```

and the jobs were executed sequentially.

My question is, is it expected that if stages are not explicitly defined, they will run in parallel, or is it a bug?

--

**Update**

I found that they ran in parallel because `job_build` had an `if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'` rule while `job_deploy` did not. But if both have the same rule, they run in sequence. Still weird since `job_deploy` is not supposed to run if `job_build` is not yet finished right?

Answer (score 0):

By default, gitlab-ci will execute in parallel (independently) unless you add `needs` param to create job dependencies.

> You can find the documentation here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs

Comment: Jobs in the same stage will execute in parallel but still sequenced by stage. The example above is in different stages, they should have executed in sequence.